# setting FOV=120 in AFRAME doesn't work in VR-MODE?

Tags: aframe

I set camera fov to be 120:

```
<a-camera fov="120"></a-camera>
```

It works well in regular mode (shows 120 fov correctly) but when I enter vr-mode in a mobile device it returns to 80. Is it a bug?

[see reproduction here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/skillful-popcorn?path=index.html:1:0)

I also opened an issue in [aframe github issue page](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3925)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's expected behavior. FOV and other camera parameters are supplied by the WebVR / WebXR API when in VR mode. [They're specific to the headset characteristics (IPD, lenses properties...)](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/camera.md#vr-behavior) and cannot be overridden. Stereo rendering would not look right with different parameters.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply;

could you direct me to a resource that says so other than aframe? i have seen fov in vr before as far as i remember... 
it makes for a very weird UX - when i switch to mobile device it looks completely different

Comment: That's how VR hardware works, not an A-Frame / WebVR / browser limitation. You have to apply the parameters provided by the WebVR / WebXR API that are ultimately supplied by the hardware. You cannot assume a certain FOV or expect to be consistent across devices. e.g: Rift is ~80 degrees FOV while the new Pimax headsets have ~170 degrees FOV. That's a property of the hardware and not software configurable