# Does not work on android phone in google chrome

Tags: aframe

Does not work on android phone in google chrome and in WebView app in Android Studio in VR Camera mode.fov. It works normally. Also noticed that the cursor does not work in version 1.0.3 in version 1.0.1 the cursor works. I attach an example with fov. Here it does not work.

```
<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
  <a-assets>
    <img id="room1" src="img/pano_1.jpg">
  </a-assets>
  <!-- room teleport hotspots -->

  <a-entity id="cam" camera="fov:80" position="0 1.6 0" look-controls
            animation__zoomin="property:camera.fov;dur:5000;delay:5000;to:40"
            animation__zoomout="property:camera.fov;dur:10;delay:10000;to:80">
  </a-entity>
  <a-sky id="skybox" src="#room1"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Animation of the camera properties fov in VR mode on Android in google chrome. I want to make the effect of approximation and deletion in my project.

Comment: I found the answer to this question. It turns out this has never worked and will not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870608/setting-fov-120-in-aframe-doesnt-work-in-vr-mode/53871203